# Background img not showing up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background header image to be responsive. I need it to be 100% of the viewport height or the image height, whichever is smaller.

An example would be the header banner similar to https://brittanychiang.com/v1/

The div size looks correct but the image don't seems to be showing up?

Created a jsfiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/pnnxm1yf/2/

```css
header {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 850px;
}

#header-banner {
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://unsplash.com/?photo=gzH1qxPLXtA) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Why is my image not showing up?</p>
<header>
  <section id="header-banner">
  </section>
</header>
 <p>content after image</p>
```

Comment: image url is wrong, and missing height :) see https://jsfiddle.net/pnnxm1yf/3/

Comment: Your image URL redirects to: `https://unsplash.com/photos/gzH1qxPLXtA`

Comment: you url doesn't refer to an image

Comment: Sorry for the wrong url linkage, but yeah setting the height to the element that houses the background image solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%` to your `#header-banner`. Its height is 0 atm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the height property onto the same element that has the background image.

```
#header-banner {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 850px;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://unsplash.com/?photo=gzH1qxPLXtA) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding height to your header-banner will solve the issue.
Plus, please get your image url correct.

```
#header-banner {
    color: #fff;
    /* background: #ffffff url(img_tree.png) center center no-repeat; */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(https://unsplash.com/?photo=gzH1qxPLXtA) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /* background-color: red; */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not add the img url properly & if you solve it you will get your output 
properly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#borderimg { 
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Safari 3.1-5 */
    -o-border-image: url(border.png) 30 round; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
    border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
</style>

<p id="borderimg">Here, the middle sections of the image are repeated to create the border.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R27m.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
#header-banner {
  height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502582877126-512f3c5b0a64?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1001&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
```

}